# example of a sequence with no convergent subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to find/construct a sequence with no convergent subsequnces, with justification. Any suggestions?

Comment: by example $x_n=n$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: any bounded sequence on $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a convergent subsequence. Thus, your counterexample will have to be unbounded. Luckily, the obvious options at hand work.